# activator unable to create project due to 401 error

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to create a new project from activator ui but it was unable to download the seed project.  I can't believe that I'm the only one having this problem... must be a setup issue somewhere?  Any idea?

```
[ERROR] [09/01/2016 18:25:39.230] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [ActorSystem(default)] Failed to download http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/templates/b0/b0d11f/b0d11fa6-d1b3-4963-94aa-319a15612bf3.zip: sbt.TranslatedIOException: Error opening http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/templates/b0/b0d11f/b0d11fa6-d1b3-4963-94aa-319a15612bf3.zip: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/templates/b0/b0d11f/b0d11fa6-d1b3-4963-94aa-319a15612bf3.zip
[WARN] [09/01/2016 18:25:39.234] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://default/user/template-cache] Unable to download template: b0d11fa6-d1b3-4963-94aa-319a15612bf3: activator.templates.repository.RepositoryException: Failed to download http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/templates/b0/b0d11f/b0d11fa6-d1b3-4963-94aa-319a15612bf3.zip: sbt.TranslatedIOException: Error opening http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/templates/b0/b0d11f/b0d11fa6-d1b3-4963-94aa-319a15612bf3.zip: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/templates/b0/b0d11f/b0d11fa6-d1b3-4963-94aa-319a15612bf3.zip
```

Comment: Which template, which version, which OS, which .... which which

Comment: @fatdragon I can download that file just fine. Can you try to copy that url and open it in your browser (or using wget)? Maybe you are in a network where you have to authenticate yourself before using it?

Comment: It works now... I swear I didn't make any changes so perhaps it's networking hiccup...  thanks all